# Post request to php Xamarin.Forms

Tags: php, xamarin, post, xamarin.forms, httpclient

I have this function inside a static class that sends a post request to a php code on my server:

```
public static string phone;

public static async Task<string> CheckPhone()
{
    string url = "my url...";
    var form = new CheckPhoneForm { Phone = phone };
    var content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(form);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(content));
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode == false) return "ERROR";
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

CheckPhoneForm class:

```
public class CheckPhoneForm
{
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}
```

php code:

```
<?php

    $phone = $_POST["Phone"];

    //rest of the code.....

?>
```

for some reason the $phone in the php file doesn't receive the data sent from the c# code and it stays empty.
can anyone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Comment: You are probably not sending the data in one of the two formats that PHP “recognizes”, when it comes to populating $_POST. You need to send a request that is either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: application/x-www-form-urlenncoded worked! can u post it as an answer so that I can mark it as solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably not sending the data in one of the two formats that PHP “recognizes”, when it comes to populating $_POST.

You need to send a request that is either `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data`.

(The body of requests sending other `Content-Types` can still be read in PHP, but that needs to happen via `php://input` then, and any parsing of the content would have to be done manually. For example when sending JSON data, this is a commonly followed approach.)